# Свойство класса - ссылка на другое свойство

Tags: php

У класса есть свойство `options` - массив,
которое по умолчанию инициализируется так:

```
[
   'main' => [ ['data' => [ .. ], .. ] ..],
   'other' => [ .. ],
   ...
]
```

в классе часто нужно будет работать с элементов `data`, чтобы каждый раз не писать так: `$this->options['main']['data']`, хотел бы завести новое свойство-ссылку, на $this->options['main']['data'], и обращаться к нему так: `$this->data`.

Можно ли при объявлении свойства класса, сразу указать, что он будет ссылкой на другое свойство?

На подобии такого:

```
public $options = [ ... ];
public $data = &$this->options['main']['data'];
```

или как решать вопрос?

Comment: в чем сложность проверить сей вопрос на практике?

Comment: `Ссылкой на другое свойство` - вы просите другого - вы хотите ссылку на элемент массива, которого, в общем случае может и не быть. Эту ссылку вы всегда можете забиндить в конструкторе класса, однако лучше пересмотреть использование свойства options, оно слишком объектно-неориентированное)

Comment: @teran 17к репутации, а пишешь какую-то чушь.
Что тут можно на практике проверить? Я написал где-то рабочий код, который можно проверить? Вопрос заключался в том, что каким образом можно такое реализовать.

Comment: вы вот эти две строки вставили в код? что вам пхп сказал на это? Надо полагать, что выражения не допустимы при определении значений свойства класса. Какие еще могут быть вопросы? Никаким образом вы не сделаете это пр объявлении свойства класса. Создать такую ссылку вы можете, очевидно, в конструкторе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы наверное это сделал так:

```
public $options = [...];
public $mainData = null;

public function __construct()
{
     $this->mainData =& $this->options['main']['data']; 
}
```

В этом случае, $mainData и $this->options['main']['data'], будут ссылаться на одно значение.

Дайте мне знать, если я вдруг не правильно понял, Ваш вопрос.